# Database Table: Quantity or redundancy

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm building a database which have a lot of items for a bike shop. This bike shop have many of the same items such as 100 wheels of size 4 and color 'red'. My question is:

Is is better to add a 'Quantity' field to the entity set and put all similar items in one entity (example 1) or is it better to have an entity for each item (example 2)?

Example 1:

**id | color |  size |  quantity**

1  | red  |   4   |   100

Example 2:

**id | color | size**

1 |  red  |   4

2  | red  |   4

3  | red  |   4

etc.

Comment: if you don't need to monitor each item, separately, clearly the first example is the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first - qqhantity field - unless you have a reason to track for example serial numbers, and even then you may go to v1 and use a separate column.

Generally: get a copy of the Data Model Ressoure Book Vol 1 - it has a ton of discussions about standard business data problems, among them an inventory system. You will learn a lot.